# C naming conventions for numeric functions?

Tags: c, naming-conventions

Say I have this function:

```
int epic(int);
```

I know of these naming conventions, are these right? Do other very common ones exist?

```
              long epicl   (long);
         long long epicll  (long long);
      unsigned int epicu   (unsigned int);
     unsigned long epicul  (unsigned long);
unsigned long long epicull (unsigned long long);
            double fepic   (double);
             float fepicf  (float);
```

Comment: `long double fepicl(long double);` and maybe (JK) `uint64_t epicu64(uint64_t);`

Comment: @close voter: Not constructive? _We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or __specific expertise__._ I'd really like to know this, because I'm writing some numerical libraries, and for my general knowledge.

Comment: the standard math function come without leading `f...` if there's no ambiguity

Comment: If you have a C11 compiler, you have generics to solve this naming mess. See eg. http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, if the return type differs from the argument type(s), a prefix is used to indicate this. Consider for example the following (from C99):

```
double round(double x);
float roundf(float x);
long double roundl(long double x);

long int lround(double x);
long int lroundf(float x);
long int lroundl(long double x);

long long int llround(double x);
long long int llroundf(float x);
long long int llroundl(long double x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you pretty much summed up most of them. A few you forgot are

```
long double fepicl(long double); /* thanks @pmg */
double epich(double); /* if epic is a hyperbolic function  */
```

In some embedded systems like ARM:

```
/* disclaimer, once saw them in an unofficial ARM SDK,
 * not sure if these conventions are standard */
u8 epic_8(u8);  
u16 epic_16(u16);
```